# What is the right syntax to create a table in sql server based on SELECT query

Tags: sql-server

I have created a simple select query looks like a vlookup function in excel as the below query

```
SELECT [myDB].[dbo].[intrafreq_cell].[st_umts_hua_intra_relation_key]
    ,[myDB].[dbo].[umts_df_relation].[cell_name]
    ,[myDB].[dbo].[umts_df_relation].[n_cell_name]
    ,CASE 
        WHEN [myDB].[dbo].[umts_df_relation].[st_umts_df_relation_key] IS NULL
            THEN 'FALSE'
        ELSE 'TRUE'
        END
FROM [myDB].[dbo].[intrafreq_cell]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [myDB].[dbo].[umts_df_relation] ON [myDB].[dbo].[intrafreq_cell].[st_umts_hua_intra_relation_key] = [myDB].[dbo].[umts_df_relation].[st_umts_df_relation_key]
WHERE [myDB].[dbo].[umts_df_relation].[st_umts_df_relation_key] = 'FALSE'
```

Now I need to create a table based on this query that contains the same columns but create a new column for the column which contains `TRUE` & `FALSE` by calling this column `missing_rel_in_df`

I just want to use `CREATE TABLE` query instead of `SELECT TABLE` query based on this `SELECT` query

Comment: In addition to the two answers mentioning `select into`, keep in mind that if you don't want the data populated, you can use `select top 0 ... into..`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add a INTO at the end of the SELECT part to indicate that you want to create a new table with the result of that query.

```
  SELECT 
      [myDB].[dbo].[intrafreq_cell].[st_umts_hua_intra_relation_key]
      ,[myDB].[dbo].[umts_df_relation].[cell_name]
      ,[myDB].[dbo].[umts_df_relation].[n_cell_name]
      ,CASE WHEN [myDB].[dbo].[umts_df_relation].[st_umts_df_relation_key] IS NULL THEN 'FALSE' ELSE  'TRUE' END AS missing_rel_in_df
  INTO MY_NEW_TABLE     
  FROM [myDB].[dbo].[intrafreq_cell] 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN [myDB].[dbo].[umts_df_relation] ON [myDB].[dbo].[intrafreq_cell].[st_umts_hua_intra_relation_key] = [myDB].[dbo].[umts_df_relation].[st_umts_df_relation_key] 
  WHERE [myDB].[dbo].[umts_df_relation].[st_umts_df_relation_key] = 'FALSE'
```

PS: remember to set the name "missing_rel_in_df" for your calculated column, so that column will have this name on the new table.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `SELECT . . . INTO` :

```
SELECT . . .
INTO <table_name>
FROM [myDB].[dbo].[intrafreq_cell] LEFT OUTER JOIN
     [myDB].[dbo].[umts_df_relation] 
     ON [myDB].[dbo].[intrafreq_cell].[st_umts_hua_intra_relation_key] = [myDB].[dbo].[umts_df_relation].[st_umts_df_relation_key] 
 WHERE [myDB].[dbo].[umts_df_relation].[st_umts_df_relation_key] = 'FALSE';
```

By this way, you will have auto created table with required data returned from `select` statement. In SQL Server `CREATE TABLE` statement is independent work. You can't merge it with `select` statement.

If you don't want data, only schema then you can add `where` clause with false condition such as :

```
WHERE 1 = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [Into](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-into-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) as shown below.

```
Select * into <NewTablenameTobeCreated> from <oldAvailableTablename>
```

> You can pass condition like where condition, aggregate function, top
>   n, etc. while selecting the record.

It will be easy to understand if you will separate the into command in two parts.

The first part will be the columns for which you want to create the table and another will be the data source column like a normal select statement.